# The 'Company' property 'Demand.Company' could not be mapped because the database provider does not support this type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm creating class maps for my models but this type error keeps happening when the application tries to migrate the database. I initially thought that the problem was the absence of the shadow properties for the relationships between tables, but it persists even after they are created and configured.

Here are my models and the respective Mappings:

Company Model

```
namespace Api.Domain.Model
{
    public class Company : BaseTable
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Cnpj { get; set; }
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Demand> Demands { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Demand Model

```
namespace Api.Domain.Model
{
    public class Demand : BaseTable
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
        public virtual string Department { get; set; }
        public virtual string Benefits { get; set; }
        public virtual string Details { get; set; }
        public virtual string Restrictions { get; set; }
        public virtual string Keywords { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Responsible { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Match> Matches { get; set; }

        // Shadow Properties
        public virtual int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public virtual int ResponsibleId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Company Map

```
namespace Api.Domain.Map
{
    public class CompanyMap : BaseMap<Company>
    {
        protected override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Company> builder)
        {
            // Primary Key
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            // Properties
            builder.Property(x => x.Id).UseIdentityColumn();
            builder.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
            builder.Property(x => x.Cnpj).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(14);
            builder.Property(x => x.Email).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
            builder.Property(x => x.Description).HasMaxLength(1000);

            // Relationships
            builder.Navigation(x => x.Demands);

            // Indexes
            builder.HasIndex(x => x.Cnpj).IsUnique();
            builder.HasIndex(x => x.Email).IsUnique();
        }
    }
}
```

Demand Map

```
namespace Api.Domain.Map
{
    public class DemandMap : BaseMap<Demand>
    {
        protected override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Demand> builder)
        {
            // Primary Key
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            // Properties
            builder.Property(x => x.Id).UseIdentityColumn();
            builder.Property(x => x.Title).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
            builder.Property(x => x.Description).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(1000);
            builder.Property(x => x.Department).HasMaxLength(255);
            builder.Property(x => x.Benefits).HasMaxLength(1000);
            builder.Property(x => x.Details).HasMaxLength(1000);
            builder.Property(x => x.Restrictions).HasMaxLength(1000);
            builder.Property(x => x.Keywords).HasMaxLength(255);

            // Relationships
            builder.Navigation(x => x.Matches);

            builder.HasOne<Company>()
                .WithMany(c => c.Demands)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.CompanyId)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.HasOne<Person>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ResponsibleId)
                .IsRequired();

            // Indexes
            builder.HasIndex(x => x.Company);
            builder.HasIndex(x => x.Responsible);
        }
    }
}
```

As the title says, the error is: `The 'Company' property 'Demand.Company' could not be mapped because the database provider does not support this type. Consider converting the property value to a type supported by the database using a value converter. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-value-converters for more information. Alternately, exclude the property from the model using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.`. Any idea What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Entity Framework Core is having trouble mapping the Company property within the Demand class to the database, because you are trying to map them directly, Instead, you should map the relationship between Demand and Company using navigation properties.

Comment: The term "shadow property" is not correct here.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure `builder.HasOne<Company>()` isn't valid (Edit: in the scenario where you have a bi-directional reference with navigation properties on both sides), it should look like:

```
 builder.HasOne(x => x.Company)
            .WithMany(c => c.Demands)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.CompanyId)
            .IsRequired();
```

Edit: You might also remove: `builder.Navigation(x => x.Demands);` from the company configuration. With the configured `HasMany()` this isn't required.

Comment: This is correct, but it would be valid if `Demand` didn't have a navigation property `Company`, only the foreign `CompanyId`.

Comment: Which his entitiy does have. It would seem to be an backwards way to configure a unidirectional relationship rather than configuring it from the side of the entity that does have the navigation property: (Company:  `builder.HasMany(x=>x.Demands).WithOne().HasForeignKey(x=>x.CompanyId);`) I can't say I have ever tried configuring it the other way around. :)

Comment: Yes, that would be a more natural way to configure it if for whatever valid reason a reference nav property is not desired. But anyway, the empty overload *can* be used, just not here as you correctly indicated.